# C# GetProcessesByName: issue with colon

Tags: c#, windows, process

I am matching a string with system processes via GetProcessesByName and it fails if a colon is being used.

The Process is *Title: Tagline* and this is my current situation
`Process.GetProcessesByName("Title: Tagline");` >  fails 
`Process.GetProcessesByName("Title:");` > fails
`Process.GetProcessesByName("Title");` > runs as expected

How can I use the full name including the colon?

thanks in advance for any advice

/edit

so I was able to digg a bit into this. 
When outputting all processes in C#, the process is actually just called *Title*.
Checking inside the task manager, it is called *Title: Tagline*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task Manager's first column shows the "display name" for the process, which is not necessarily the same as process name.

You can enable display of process by right-clicking the table heading in TM and enabling "Process Name" column.

Alternatively, you can inspect output of [Process.GetProcesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8) to find the intended name of the desired process.

If you need to find a processes based on window title, you could iterate over output of GetProcesses and check MainWindowTitle, or use the "raw" [FindWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) function (which will also find non-main windows).

Comment: *If you need to find a processes based on window title, you could iterate over output of GetProcesses and check MainWindowTitle, or use the "raw" FindWindow function (which will also find non-main windows).* oh wow. thanks for that input. I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Just look with the shell how your task is called. With `tasklist` you will see all running tasks. I grant you, there is no colon.